# finally not throwing stack overflow exception

Tags: java, exception, stack-overflow

As far as I know this code should throw StackOverflowError, but it isn't. What could be the reason?

```
public class SimpleFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("main");

        try{
        SimpleFile.main(args);
            }

        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Catch");
        }

        finally{
            SimpleFile.main(args);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I guess its because main being a static method is not created on stack instead its created on PermGen section of heap so everytime we call it previous instance gets lost, if u put this code  `new SimpleFile().abc()`
 immediately after ur main method and create method `void abc() {abc(); }` then definetly its throwing stackoverflow exception because non-static  methods are created on stack.

Comment: @3kings that makes no sense. are you saying simple methods like `void foo() {System.out.println("foo"); foo(); }` wouldn't throw stack overflow?

Comment: @Aamir wouldn't that be an answer?

Comment: @eis I was not sure if this was the reason

Comment: @Aamir I guess not `public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        A.test();
    }

    
    public static void test() 
    {
       
        A.main(null);
    }

}`

Answer (score 5):

An [Error](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) is not an `Exception`. So catching any exception won't catch the StackOverflowError.

So lets start by fixing the "obvious mistake" - *(this code is inadvisable as stated later in this answer)*:

```
    catch(Throwable e){
        System.out.println("Catch");
    }
```

If you make this change you will find the code still does not print.  But it doesn't print for a very different reason...

Catching any `ERROR` (including a `StackOverflowError`) is highly discouraged.  But here you are not only catching one, you're catching one as it happens at the top of the stack.  Even with your code (without the above change) the error is effectively caught by the `finally` block.

A `StackOverflowError` occurs when the stack is full and you try to add more to it.  So when you catch the error the stack is still full.  You can not call any method (even to print to the console) because the stack is full.  So a second `StackOverflowError` is thrown in the `catch` before it has successfully printed.

The result of this is that it:

1. Catches the error
2. trys to print the error
3. causes another error because it can't print
4. calls `finally`, because finally is *always* called.
5. causes another error because it cant call `main`
6. cascades the error back to the previous call which runs into the same error.

The key here is that *eventually* it will start printing something.  But the call to `print` uses a lot of stack space and your code will have to recurs and error through the above points for a *very long time* before it ever frees up enough stack space to print.  According to Holger's comment With Oracle’s Java 8 to put the number of `main` stack frames needed for a `println` stack frame close to 50.

```
250 = 1,125,899,906,842,624
```

This is why **YOU SHOULD NEVER CATCH ERRORS**.

There are only a handful of excuses that allow you to break this rule, and you've discovered first hand what can go wrong if you do break it.

Comment: That's right - but shouldn't the code then go into the finally block and then throw another StackOverflowError when it attempts to call SimpleFile.main(args); again?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm investigating now. It looks like a bit of a bug. Maybe with the optimiser.

Comment: I've got it! Catching throwable is BAD. Catching a stack overflow exception as it happens is VERY BAD. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Holger As many discovered, simply changing from `catch (Exception e)` to `catch (Throwable e)` was not sufficient to fix the problem.  It is on first glance the problem with what the OP's code but there is more at play than just that. The code change got lost my edits. I can put it back in to make the answer more clear.

Comment: Now it’s understandable. You may add that the `println` requires much more stack size than the `main` method, so between the first occurrence of a `StackOverflowError` and the first printing of a `Catched` it will perform `2ⁿ` more invocations of `main` where `n` is determined by the difference of the required stack size of flat `main` and a complete `print` operations. With Oracle’s Java 8, `n` seems to be close to `50` here…

Answer (score 3):

Actually you got java.lang.Stackoverflow

You can run this sample code:

```
public class SimpleFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("main ");
       try{
          SimpleFile.main(args);
       }finally{
          try{
             SimpleFile.main(args);
          }catch(Error e2){
             System.out.println("finally");
             throw e2;
          }
       }
   }
}
```

PS

More details: your program prints a lot of `main` messages and after this you receives stack overflow error for first time and go to finally block. It means that you decrease stack size and now you can call something. But you call itself in finally block and get stack overflow again. Most surprising for me was unstable output:

```
 main 
 main main finally
 main 
 main main finallyfinallyfinally
 main 
 main
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you have a `catch` clause which doesn’t catch `Error`s:

```
catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Catch");
}
```

Since `Error`s are not `Exception`s, this does not catch `StackOverflowError`s and the print statement will not get executed. If an `Error` is not catched, it’s stack trace will get printed by the default handler of a thread, if it ever reaches that point. But you have another clause:

```
finally{
    SimpleFile.main(args);
}
```

The code of the `finally` clause will always get executed when the `try` block completes, whether normally or exceptionally. Since your `try` block contains an infinite recursion, it will never complete normally.

In the exceptional case, i.e. when a `StackOverflowError` is thrown, the `finally` action will go into into an infinite recursion again, which may again eventually fail with a `StackOverflowError`, but since it bears the same `finally` block, it will also go into the infinite recursion again.

Your program is basically saying “perform an infinite recursion, then another infinite recursion”. Note that you can’t distinguish from the printing of `"main"` whether the program runs in the primary infinite recursion or one triggered from a `finally` block (except that line breaks might be missing if a stackoverflow happens right in between the `println` execution).

So if we assume that a particular JVM has a limit of `1000` nested invocations, your program will perform `2¹⁰⁰⁰` invocations of your `main` method ([quantification](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E1000&num=1)). Since your `main` method actually does nothing, an optimizer could elide even this incredible number of invocations, but this optimization also implies that the required stack size vanishes and thus, an even higher number of recursive invocations becomes possible. Only a JVM implementation enforcing an intentional limit on the supported number of recursive invocations, independent from the actually required stack space, could enforce this program to ever terminate.

But note, that in the case of an infinite recursion, there is no guaranty to get a `StackOverflowError` at all. Theoretically, a JVM having an infinite stack space would be a valid implementation. This implies that a JVM, practically optimizing recursive code to run without requiring additional stack space, would be valid too.

So for a typical implementation like Oracle’s JVM, it is practically impossible for your program to ever report a `StackOverflowError`. They happen, but are shadowed by your follow-up recursions in the `finally` block, thus are never reported.

Comment: I like this exploration of the theory.  I'm not much of a fan of hypothetical situations based on infinity.  They have a tenancy to trick you into thinking something is possible for finite situations which really isn't.  A JVM with an unlimited stack would still fail (hopefully reporting a `StackOverflowError`) if only when ran out of RAM or swap space.

Comment: @couling: the JVM with infinite stack space may also have the required infinite RAM. It doesn’t matter that such a thing doesn’t exist. It’s only a mental model to explain, that it is legal for a JVM to transform this recursion into an infinite loop printing `"main"` forever without ever throwing. And such a transformation *exists*. It’s called “tail call optimization” and while Oracle’s JVM doesn’t have it, others may have.

Comment: @couling: not exactly. This roulette strategy is guaranteed to win in the case it completes. But it is not guaranteed to ever complete… Regarding stack traces, a JVM could simply count the number of recursions and repeat the relevant entry in the stack as needed. Note that Oracle’s current implementation *has* a limit on the number of stack trace entries, and in some situations, it already doesn’t provide a stack trace at all, even without tail call optimization.

Comment: @couling: you are changing the definition. The roulette strategy works, if you have infinite money, infinite time and no limit for the bets. Once you confront one of these constraints with reality, this strategy *doesn’t work* (and hence, isn’t worth discussing). As said, Oracle’s JVM already *has* a limit for stack traces (1024), so a counting solution will be compatible with that if the counter is capable of holding a number up to that, which is not too far fetched. If the recursion goes deeper, you’ll lose the capability to report the exact number, but this doesn’t differ to today’s JVM.

Comment: *"Once you confront one of these constraints with reality, this strategy doesn’t work"* That is exactly the point I'm making.  We appear to now be violently agreeing. My first comment was *"I'm not much of a fan of hypothetical situations based on infinity. They have a tendency to trick you into thinking something is possible for finite situations which really isn't."*

Answer (score 0):

I have done some modification to your code and have done some tests. I still cannot figure out an answer to your question. It is the finally block for sure that causes the whole wearied behavior of the code.

```
public class SimpleFile {

    static int i = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int c = i++;
        System.out.println("main" + i);

        try {
            SimpleFile.main(args);
        }

        catch (Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("Catch" + e);
        }

        finally {
            if (i < 30945) {
                System.out.println("finally" + c);
                SimpleFile.main(args);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the out put is.. i am only showing the last lines:

```
main30941
main30942finally30940
main30943finally30927
main30944
main30945
main30946
main30947Catchjava.lang.StackOverflowError
```

I want to prove that even static methods do get StackOverflowError if called recursively. And since you were catching exception that would never catch an Error.

See [Call Main Recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22624983/call-main-recursively) question for StackOverflowError if main is called recursively

Answer (score -1):

Static methods are permanent, it is not stored in a stack but, in a heap instead. The code code you wrote simply calls the same code over and over from the heap, so it won't throw `StackOverFlowError`. Also, the string inside `System.out.println("main");` is stored in the same location which is permanent. Even though you called the code over and over, the same object of string is used, it won't fill the stack.

I got this explanation from the following link :

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memleaks-137499.html#gbyuu

> 3.1.2 Detail Message: PermGen space The detail message PermGen space indicates that the permanent generation is full. The permanent
>   generation is the area of the heap where class and method objects are
>   stored. If an application loads a very large number of classes, then
>   the size of the permanent generation might need to be increased using
>   the -XX:MaxPermSize option.
>
> Interned java.lang.String objects are also stored in the permanent
>   generation. The java.lang.String class maintains a pool of strings.
>   When the intern method is invoked, the method checks the pool to see
>   if an equal string is already in the pool. If there is, then the
>   intern method returns it; otherwise it adds the string to the pool. In
>   more precise terms, the java.lang.String.intern method is used to
>   obtain the canonical representation of the string; the result is a
>   reference to the same class instance that would be returned if that
>   string appeared as a literal. If an application interns a huge number
>   of strings, the permanent generation might need to be increased from
>   its default setting.
>
> When this kind of error occurs, the text String.intern or
>   ClassLoader.defineClass might appear near the top of the stack trace
>   that is printed.
>
> The jmap -permgen command prints statistics for the objects in the
>   permanent generation, including information about internalized String
>   instances.

Comment: it is not true that static methods don't throw StackOverFlowError

Comment: You are getting confused between the memory used to store program code and the memory used to store "stack frames".  Regardless of whether a method is static or not, calls to it must generate stack frames otherwise java will loose track of how many times it has recursed in.

Comment: @couling: in case of a tail-call optimization, the number of recursive invocations may indeed get lost, but Oracle’s JVM doesn’t perform this kind of optimization. Still, the number of possible recursions depends on the optimization state of a method, but you’re right, this has nothing to do with the method being `static` or not.