# Why doesn't code trying to catch a StackOverflowError run?

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow, try-finally

This question extends from [Try-finally block prevents StackOverflowError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438786/try-finally-block-prevents-stackoverflowerror).

If I add a catch block, why catch block codes never runs?

```
public static void foo() {
    try {
        foo();
    } catch(StackOverflowError e) {       
       System.exit(1); // or System.err.println("ouch!"); whatever
    } finally {
        foo();
    }
}
```

I refer to [JLS Chapter 11.1.3 - Asynchronous Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html) - is it the reason cause catch block have no chance to run?

Comment: How can `StackOverflowError.` happen here?

Comment: "it's not working" doesn't describe the behaviour you expect or the behaviour you observe.

Comment: Thanks I edit the question to write whole method and some description

Comment: Because "it will take a really, really long time" to throw the StackOverflowError. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12439093/1048340

Comment: As per your linked question, the `finally` is run before the exception is thrown, so it recurses through `foo()` for a very long time before the first exception is thrown.

Comment: @jared-rummler In the link's replying suppose we have max depth 5 so the first "foo() which fails to call foo()" should reach very quickly, my question is why it is not able be catch by a proper catch block.

Comment: @evan-knowles That's not true. The first StackOverflowError will be throw just follows the first finally completes abruptly, if max depth is 5 the stack will fluctuate in 4 and 5 during whole process. I believe it is but can't prove it yet.